# MediaWiki stylesheet is not loading - only on the MainPage it functions properly // DependencyError: Unknown module: mediawiki.page.startup

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, mediawiki, fastcgi

I fear that I'm only missing one small thing but I can't find it.

I have set up a MediaWiki page on a VPS (Ubuntu 16.04.) with nginx and for the most part it seems to be working.
The one big problem is that only the Main Page is loading the stylesheet but others do not.

I get this error in the Chrome console:

```
Refused to apply style from '***/load.php?lang=en&modules=ext.visualEditor.desktopArticleTarget.noscript%7Cmediawiki.action.edit.styles%7Cmediawiki.editfont.styles%7Cmediawiki.widgets.styles%7Coojs-ui-core.icons%2Cstyles%7Coojs-ui.styles.indicators%7Cskins.vector.styles.legacy&only=styles&skin=vector' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

And these warnings:

```
DependencyError: Unknown module: mediawiki.page.startup
```

```
Skipped unresolvable module ext.visualEditor.desktopArticleTarget.init
```

When I go to the page from that error I get an error code 500 and 2 PHP warnings:

```
Warning: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in /var/www/mediawiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php on line 348

Warning: Attempt to read property "firstChild" on null in /var/www/mediawiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php on line 352
```

Not sure what is there left that I should provide, here is my nginx config:

```
 # HTTPS Configuration
 server {
 
     listen 80;
     
     server_name ***.com www.***.com;
     root /var/www/mediawiki;
 
     index index.php;
     autoindex off;
 
     client_max_body_size 5m;
     client_body_timeout 60;
 
     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
     }
 
     location @rewrite {
         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1&$args;
     }
 
     location ^~ /maintenance/ {
         return 403;
     }
 
     # PHP Configuration
     location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     }
 
     location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
         try_files $uri /index.php;
         expires max;
         log_not_found off;
     }
 
     location = /_.gif {
         expires max;
         empty_gif;
     }
 
     location ^~ ^/(cache|includes|maintenance|languages|serialized|tests|images/deleted)/ {
         deny all;
     }
 
     location ^~ ^/(bin|docs|extensions|includes|maintenance|mw-config|resources|serialized|tests)/ {
         internal;
     }
 
     # Security for 'image' directory
     location ~* ^/images/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
         types { }
         default_type text/plain;
     }
 
     # Security for 'image' directory
     location ^~ /images/ {
         try_files $uri /index.php;
     }
 
 }
```

Is the Skin broken? Or the entire Page/nginx conf? I'm unsure how/where to debug that problem.

Comment: I suggest that you run `git submodule update --init` and `composer update` in both *MediaWiki* root directory and `extensions/VisualEditor`. Also, make sure that *MediaWiki* core and *Visual Editor* have the same git branch/release.
If this does not help, switch *Visual Editor* off altogether and see if this helps.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I turned off the VisualEditor for now to debug/test stuff. But with no real progress.. it's still not loading the stylesheet in the edit page, with the exact same error (MIME type thing)

Comment: Purge browser cache with Ctrl+F5 on edit page.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I did that, still the same problem.